# Exporting functional component does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, functional-programming

I'm exporting my screen called Bus as a function instead of a react class component and always receive an error screen saying: 'Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Bus`.'

Makes no sense to me, since i'm also using functional components in others places and it works fine!

I'm using RN 0.60.5

My **Bus page** which gives me the error.

```
import React, { View, Text } from 'react';

import Maps from '../../components/Maps'
import SearchBox from '../../components/Searchbox'
import RouteDetailsBox from '../../components/RouteDetailsBox'

const Bus = () => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Maps />
        <SearchBox />
        <RouteDetailsBox />
    </View>
);

export default Bus;
```

**App.js**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store';


//screens
import Bus from './src/screens/bus'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Bus />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPLZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from

```
import React, { View, Text } from 'react';
```

to

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
```